# tsql XML explicit path

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, cdata, for-xml

I have query:

`select 1 as Tag , 
0 as Parent ,
'<P>' + 'Name' + ' ' + 'SurName' + '</P>' as "name!1!!CDATA" 
from tPA_SysParamSys
for xml explicit, root('customers')`

which output is:

`<customers>
  <name><![CDATA[<P>Name SurName</P>]]></name>
</customers>`

But instead I wanna:

`<customer>
    <customers>
        <name><![CDATA[<P>Name SurName</P>]]></name>
    </customers>
</customer>`

Without EXPLICIT and CDATA but with PATH I can do that, but can't do with CDATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, what you really want. I assume, that your root node should be `<customers>` (plural), while each row is one `<customer>`. I assume, that `Name` and `SurName` are columns living within your table.

Might be, it's this you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE([Name] VARCHAR(100),SurName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES('Smith','Tim'),('Fonda','Jane');

select 1 as Tag , 
0 as Parent ,
'<P>' + Name + ' ' + SurName + '</P>' as "customer!1!name!CDATA" 
from @mockupTable 
for xml explicit, root('customers');
```

The result

```
<customers>
  <customer>
    <name><![CDATA[<P>Smith Tim</P>]]></name>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name><![CDATA[<P>Fonda Jane</P>]]></name>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

But please allow me the question: Why?

There is absolutely no need for `CDATA` sections. A properly escaped normal `text()` node is semantically identical. SQL-Server developers decided not even to support this anymore...

If you store an XML including `CDATA` sections, they are translated implicitly. Try it out:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<customers>
  <customer>
    <name><![CDATA[<P>Smith Tim</P>]]></name>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name><![CDATA[<P>Fonda Jane</P>]]></name>
  </customer>
</customers>';
SELECT @xml;
```

You get this:

```
<customers>
  <customer>
    <name>&lt;P&gt;Smith Tim&lt;/P&gt;</name>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name>&lt;P&gt;Fonda Jane&lt;/P&gt;</name>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

Comment: Specification it's with CDATA and must be.

Comment: @kole1108, well, sometimes we have to live with it... :-D Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

With this query ...

```
with c 
as 
( 
select 1 as CustomerId, 'Name1' as Name1, 'Name2' as Name2 
union select 2, 'Name1', 'Name2' 
) 
select 1 as Tag 
    , 0 as Parent 
    , CustomerId as "customer!1!customer_id!hide" 
    , null as "name!2!!CDATA" 
from c 
union 
select 2 as Tag 
    , 1 as Parent 
    , CustomerId 
    , Name1 + ' ' + Name2 as "name!2!!CDATA" 
from tCustomers c 
order by "customer!1!customer_id!hide", Tag 
for xml explicit, root('customers')
```

You get this XML ...

```
<customers>
  <customer>
    <name><![CDATA[Comp1Name1 Comp1Name2]]></name>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name><![CDATA[Comp2Name1 Comp2Name2]]></name>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

Inspired by this link ... https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26194239/CDATA-tags-appearing-incorrectly-in-XML-output-using-FOR-XML-PATH.html

Comment: Between the `!!` in `"name!2!!CDATA" ` you are renouncing the level which you have to introduce with a `UNION` later. This can be done straight forward...